# Custom URL and HTTPS in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, https, uri, custom-url

I'm trying to open my app via a custom URL in WP8. I.E, when a link like "myurl://..." is clicked on the browser, it needs to open my app.
Now, when I try to do it from a HTTP link, it works. But when I try to do that from a HTTPS link, I see my app flashing but not a single line of code is processed (not even the "initializeComponent" function of my MainPage.xaml which is, of what I know, the first function to be called when an app is called. So what really happens ? Is there any way to fix this ?
If it can help, I have an SSL certificate for my https page and it is installed on the phone so I don't think it comes from there...